# Can I get new account but keep my current Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I want to join a different team, is there a way to start a new account and just transfer my Pokemon, or would I have to completely start over?

Comment: In what Pokémon game?

Comment: If you start a new account, you have to start over. That is sort of the definition of a new account. It is new.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to switch teams that does not involve starting over from scratch. So no, you would not be able to transfer your current Pokémons.